# Wildcard Downloads with Python

Tags: python

How can I download files from a website using wildacrds in Python?  I have a site that I need to download file from periodically.  The problem is the filenames change each time.  A portion of the file stays the same though.  How can I use a wildcard to specify the unknown portion of the file in a URL?

Answer (score 7):

If the filename changes, there must still be a *link* to the file somewhere (otherwise nobody would ever guess the filename). A typical approach is to get the HTML page that contains a link to the file, search through that looking for the link target, and then send a second request to get the actual file you're after.

Web servers do not generally implement such a "wildcard" facility as you describe, so you must use other techniques.

Answer (score 1):

You could try logging into the ftp server using [ftplib](http://python.org/doc/2.5.2/lib/module-ftplib.html).
From the python docs:

```
from ftplib import FTP
ftp = FTP('ftp.cwi.nl')   # connect to host, default port
ftp.login()               # user anonymous, passwd anonymous@
```

The ftp object has a `dir` method that lists the contents of a directory.
You could use this listing to find the name of the file you want.